# Side Load Windows Store Apps when Windows Store Blocked by Group Policy

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, side-loading

Group Policy blocks the Windows Store from opening. I have admin rights to my machine. Is there a way to download the app on another computer and then side-load it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install windows store apps without the store, (aka side-loading) you will have to first download them on a working computer and then copy it over to the computer you want to side load.

1. ### Download the Appx file of a universal store application

   - Use a network traffic monitor to locate the URL where the windows app is stored on Microsoft's servers. Fiddler, or WireShark works.
   - Download the app using windows store on the computer that works.
   - Find `appx` or `AppxBundle` in the network traffic. It will look like this

     > Result: 200, Protocol: HTTP, Host: tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com
   - Copy the URL and open it in a browser to download the app
   - Note: The url is ephemeral to your windows store download session, and will need to be downloaded quickly before it is invalidated.
2. ### Installing it in Windows

   - Sometimes you can just double click on the `.Appx` file to install it. But if it has dependencies, Double check your network traffic for other `.Appx` URLs.
   - If you need to or are having issues you can install the universal app via the command line:

`add-appxpackage -path ".\5E8FC25E.XodoDocs_4.0.3.0_neutral___3v3sf0k6w2rec.AppxBundle"`

Comment: You can use https://store.rg-adguard.net/ to find download links of the appx files